# mysql query to hide blocked user all posts

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

Table Name: user_post

```
id     user_id    post

1         2       hi ths is aaaaa

2         3       hi ths is yyyyyy
```

Table Name: user_block

```
id      post_id     user_id  block_id  status

1      1                2       4         1
```

Please tell me the select query in blocked user all posts should be hide my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_block`
  WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `post_id` FROM `user_block`
      WHERE `user_id` = '{$userID}'
      AND `status` = '1'
  )
```

But this query doesnot hide blocked user all posts

Comment: where is `hide_post` table?

Comment: i mean user_block

Comment: You want to fetch all posts from user_post without blocked users' post is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
select * from user_post
where '{$userID}' not in (
  select user_id from user_block
  where status = '1'
)
```

will hide all posts if `userid` has the value `1` inside `user_block`. 
If you want the user to see only his own posts:

```
select * from user_post
where '{$userID}' not in (
  select user_id from user_block
  where status = '1'
)
and user_id = '{$userID}'
```

Comment: left join is more efficient I think

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM user_post LEFT OUTER JOIN user_block
ON user_post.user_id = user_block.user_id
WHERE user_block.user_id IS null
```

Very useful post. Joins visually explained [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: This does not answer the question