# Select from two table where value not in nother table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two table table1 and table2. I want to select from table1 where id not in table2 id.

```
table1
id     name
001    Testing
002    Hello
003    World
004    Programmer

table2
id     name
001    Testing
003    World
```

my expectation

```
id     name
002    Hello
004    Programmer
```

i try these code

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as a where a.id <> (SELECT b.id from table2 as b )
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: Same kind of a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098921/mysql-query-to-hide-blocked-user-all-posts/55099259#55099259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query like following using `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as a where a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id from table2 as b )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a left join table2 b on a.id=b.id
where b.id is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can **NOT IN** it

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as a where a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id from table2 as b )
```

Src: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php

Comment: Thank you very much